Highlighting duplicates in Google Sheets (from a source of 1 row, not a column)
I have ROWS of names rather than columns. I simply want to highlight any time a name is duplicated in further rows.
Currently working with the names from B2:K2, which test duplicates in various cells beneath - C5, D8, E12, etc etc. I just can't figure it out, although I swear it's so simple.
SAMPLE SHEET = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTQ4LNInbFyoo0mJIWOnT1aPYB4ZzQon0L37YiAWI3w/edit?gid=0#gid=0

please share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result.

Here's a sample sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nTQ4LNInbFyoo0mJIWOnT1aPYB4ZzQon0L37YiAWI3w/edit?gid=0#gid=0

This question is similar to: Highlight Duplicates in Google Sheets. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can apply the following conditional formatting custom formula to the range B2:K:
=COUNTIF($B3:$K,B2)

This formula highlights the value in the current row if it's present in any row below.

Thank you. This works. It's not perfect with the way it highlights (consistently) some of the duplicates themselves, but it always seems to highlight in the first row. Which is definitely good enough and will always alert me to a dupe!

the formula highlights the values in the current row if they are present in any row below. If you want to highlight all the duplicates use =COUNTIF($B$2:$K,B2)>1
